# Unattended/silent install of Oracle XE Express fails

Tags: oracle, installation

I am experimenting with silent installs of Oracle 10g XE on a fresh XP VM.  I have an iss file, copied from the standard one from oracle, called "foo.iss"  Here is my command:

```
>OracleXEUniv.exe /s /f1”C:\xe\foo.iss” /f2”C:\xe\foo.log”
```

I just followed what I found on the Oracle support site.  This command causes a temp folder to be created, which contains an installer file: "Oracle Database 10g Express Edition.msi"

So it looks good.  But the process then just silently fails.  No log is created in the install folder (C:\x) except for setup.log which only has:

```
[ResponseResult]
ResultCode=-3
```

In C:\windows is the larger log file, OracleDatabaseXEServerInstall.log

Is has alot in it, and ends with:

```
1: Standard project type, let scripting engine clean up setup files...skipping action 
Action ended 17:43:27: ISSetupFilesCleanup. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (34:BC) [17:43:27:420]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ISSETUP_UISEQUENCE_PROCESSED property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (34:BC) [17:43:27:420]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Upgrade 3: -2147287038 
1: Not using skins for this installation.  Could not find skin file . 
MSI (c) (34:BC) [17:43:27:650]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DuplicateFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (34:BC) [17:43:27:700]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ISRequiredFeature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (34:BC) [17:43:27:920]: Note: 1: 2205 2: C:\DOCUME~1\dlwiii\LOCALS~1\Temp\_is33\Oracle Database 10g Express Edition.msi 3: ISAlias 
MSI (c) (34:BC) [17:43:27:920]: Note: 1: 2228 2: C:\DOCUME~1\dlwiii\LOCALS~1\Temp\_is33\Oracle Database 10g Express Edition.msi 3: ISAlias 4: SELECT * FROM ISAlias 
1: Ready to launch program block. 
1: User aborts the installation, ready to launch __OnAbort. 
MSI (c) (34:BC) [17:43:30:434]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (34:B8) [17:43:30:454]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
=== Verbose logging stopped: 8/27/2011  17:43:30 ===
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  The command line looks suspect, as when I run the install program with just /? I get the following, which shows no /f1 nor /f2 options at all:

[image]

I am simply playing with this, but would really like to solve this, as unattended installs look like a great option to ensure consistent database deployments.

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I had mistyped this line:

OracleXEUniv.exe /s /f1"c:\xe\foo.iss"  /f2"c:\xe\foo.log"

Omitted the second set of quotes.  Looks like it worked just fine.