# Silent install of Oracle XE 11g fails with error -3

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, installation, powershell

I'm trying to install silently Oracle 11g XE in the default location (C:\oraclexe).

```
PS D:\Profiles\xxx\Downloads\x.x\oraclexe\oraclexe-11.2.0> .\setup.exe /S /v/qn
```

However, the command generates a setup.log with an error -3 in it, without more information.

```
[ResponseResult]
ResultCode=-3
```

I've tried a lot of command alternatives, even by using f1 and f2 arguments, but it still does not work. No matter if it is on Powershell or the command line.

Looks like my issue sounds similar to this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5129/unattended-silent-install-of-oracle-xe-express-fails?newreg=33b48b43e380492a942b6e9ec963a134), except the answer resolves nothing.

The normal GUI installation works well.

Do you know how I can resolve this thing ? What does the result code mean ?

Thanks for reading me.

Target software : https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/xe-prior-releases-5172097.html

Comment: If there is a conflict in tns port,http port,MTS port or oracle base directory exists or not empty you run into  resultcode -3.Try to change conflicting ports in response file and delete  C:\oraclexe(and setup.log) directory or you can change oracle base directory in response file too.`D:\Downloads\OracleXE112_Win64\DISK1>setup /s /f1"D:\Downloads\OracleXE112_Win64\DISK1\response\OracleXE-install.iss" /f2"D:\Downloads\OracleXE112_Win64\DISK1\setup.log"`

Comment: Ok I will try as soon as possible.